# importxml from raw xml on gist produces error

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I have a raw xml file on Gist:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/EmDubeu/196d95b561fa83a4ef360654ed919fe5/raw/9e2dde8d08a2ea4e45871bf8c55693334f8a69e1/NEIPA.xml

I store the above url in a cell in my Google spreadsheet (`Settings!E27`).

I'm trying to use importxml from my google sheet with the following formula:
`=IMPORTXML(Settings!E27, "//HOP/NAME")`, but it returns "Error Imported Xml content can not be parsed."

My formula works with this url:
http://www.beerxml.com/recipes.xml

Why is it not working with my Gist hosted xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub is not for file-hosting and `Content-Type` headers is not set properly. If you type http://www.beerxml.com/recipes.xml in the browser, it will render the page as XML contents, but not for your https://gist.githubusercontent.com/EmDubeu/... since it cannot recognize it as a XML page.

In this case, people(at least, I) usually use sites like https://rawgit.com/. For your gist file, rawgit URL is https://rawgit.com/EmDubeu/196d95b561fa83a4ef360654ed919fe5/raw/fcb019a0db249ea90a9512f9162725547f4a43b5/NEIPA.xml.

But when I type this URL, my browser says it cannot parse the page because of characters like `&`. It should be [HTML(XML) character encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#XML_character_references). You can verify this by viewing the source of http://www.beerxml.com/recipes.xml, in which `&` is encoded to `&amp;` properly. You should html-encode your gist too.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a break line between `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` and `<RECIPES>`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I added a line break as suggested, however error still exists. I used <&#xA;> between <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> and <RECIPES> as suggested.

Comment: I copied the content from the XML that works and edited it into my gist xml file. I got the same error. I wonder if it has to do with the xml file being hosted as a shared file, even though it's set to Public on gist?